# # in text at innerHTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, dom, onclick, innerhtml

I cant figure out how i can get ", i need this in a text when using DOM.innerHTML.

```
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "<div id='info01' class='border border-3 w-50 h-50 d-flex align-content-center shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded flex-column'><h1 class='text-center'>Hent varer fra Traphous</h1><p class='text-center'><b>Kjøp noe:</b></p><button onclick='kjøp('kokain')' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Kokain</button><br><button onclick='kjøp('hasj')' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Hasj</button><br><button onclick='kjøp('amfetamin')' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Amfetamin</button><br><button onclick='kjøp('benzo')' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Benzo</button><br><button onclick='kjøp('molly')' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Molly</button></div>"
```

I need to call a function `onclick='endre("kjøp_narkotika")` I cant use `onclick='endre('kjøp_narkotika')` becuse then the function wont call.

Comment: `"use \"backslash\" to escape the nested quotes"`, or use a `\`"template" string\`` to avoid the need for escaping quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use backticks (`) instead of (")

```
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = `<div id='info01' class='border border-3 w-50 h-50 d-flex align-content-center shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded flex-column'><h1 class='text-center'>Hent varer fra Traphous</h1><p class='text-center'><b>Kjøp noe:</b></p><button onclick="kjøp('kokain')" class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Kokain</button><br><button onclick='kjøp('hasj')' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Hasj</button><br><button onclick='kjøp('amfetamin')' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Amfetamin</button><br><button onclick='kjøp('benzo')' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Benzo</button><br><button onclick='kjøp('molly')' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Molly</button></div>`
```

In the above example I have changed the Single quotes to double quotes for button click.

```
onclick="kjøp('kokain')"
```

You can see a sample here :
https://jsfiddle.net/jubish/w2ospk15/16/

Click on the button **Kokain** to see the results.

> Method 2

```
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "<div id='info01' class='border border-3 w-50 h-50 d-flex align-content-center shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded flex-column'><h1 class='text-center'>Hent varer fra Traphous</h1><p class='text-center'><b>Kjøp noe:</b></p><button onclick='kjøp( \"kokain\")' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Kokain</button><br><button onclick='kjøp('hasj')' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Hasj</button><br><button onclick='kjøp('amfetamin')' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Amfetamin</button><br><button onclick='kjøp('benzo')' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Benzo</button><br><button onclick='kjøp('molly')' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Molly</button></div>"
```

Here I have used backslash to escape the double quotes
Example :

```
 onclick='kjøp( \"kokain\")'
```

working code - https://jsfiddle.net/jubish/ez3hr7g1/8/

Comment: Thank you, So instead of DOM.innerhtml = "" I can use DOM.innerhtml = '' :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = `<div id='info01' class='border border-3 w-50 h-50 d-flex align-content-center shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded flex-column'><h1 class='text-center'>Hent varer fra Traphous</h1><p class='text-center'><b>Kjøp noe:</b></p><button onclick='kjøp("kokain")' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Kokain</button><br><button onclick='kjøp("hasj")' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Hasj</button><br><button onclick='kjøp("amfetamin")' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Amfetamin</button><br><button onclick='kjøp("benzo")' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Benzo</button><br><button onclick='kjøp("molly")' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Molly</button></div>`
    function kjøp(param){console.log(param)}
```

```html
<div id="info"></div>
```

Try this, I hope it helps.

Backticks are supported by ES6.

```
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = `<div id='info01' class='border border-3 w-50 h-50 d-flex align-content-center shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded flex-column'><h1 class='text-center'>Hent varer fra Traphous</h1><p class='text-center'><b>Kjøp noe:</b></p><button onclick='kjøp("kokain")' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Kokain</button><br><button onclick='kjøp("hasj")' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Hasj</button><br><button onclick='kjøp("amfetamin")' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Amfetamin</button><br><button onclick='kjøp("benzo")' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Benzo</button><br><button onclick='kjøp("molly")' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Molly</button></div>`
```

Method 2 : Concatenate strings

```
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "<div id='info01' class='border border-3 w-50 h-50 d-flex align-content-center shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded flex-column'><h1 class='text-center'>Hent varer fra Traphous</h1><p class='text-center'><b>Kjøp noe:</b></p><button onclick='kjøp("+'"kokain"'+")' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Kokain</button><br><button onclick='kjøp("+'"hasj"'+")' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Hasj</button><br><button onclick='kjøp("+'"amfetamin"'+")' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Amfetamin</button><br><button onclick='kjøp("+'"benzo"'+")' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Benzo</button><br><button onclick='kjøp("+'"molly"'+")' class='btn btn-primary w-50 align-self-center' type='button'>Molly</button></div>`
```

Comment: Whats the different? I cant find it..

Comment: The backtickes <<``>> these ones